# android.view.InflateException Error when using different layout file tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I have searched everywhere and cannot find the answer.  When I run the app in a non 720dp device it is fine, but when I run in a 720dp device I get an error.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have 3 activity_army_builder.xml files.  One in layout, one in layout-sw720dp-port and one in layout-sw720dp-land.  Thank you in advance

Stacktrace

```
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit, PID: 31120
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.ArmyBuilder}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.ArmyBuilder.onCreate(ArmyBuilder.java:56)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.BarracksUILarge.onCreateView(BarracksUILarge.java:53)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.ArmyBuilder.onCreate(ArmyBuilder.java:56) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.BarracksUILarge.onCreateView(BarracksUILarge.java:53) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.ArmyBuilder.onCreate(ArmyBuilder.java:56) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-20 09:50:49.221 31120-31120/com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Lay
```

activity_army_builder.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_army_builder_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />


<com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/army_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/army_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="14.4"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:elevation="2dp"/>


<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:name="com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.BarracksUILarge"
    android:id="@+id/barracks_fragment_large"
    tools:layout="@layout/barracks_ui_large"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20.7"
    android:name="com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.TotalsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/totals_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_totals"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="13.4"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

barracks_ui_large.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="@style/barracks_large_orientation"
tools:context="com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.BarracksUILarge">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/elix_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/barracks_padding_5"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnCount="19"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:rowCount="7">

</GridLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/dark_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/barracks_padding_5"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnCount="23"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:rowCount="7">


</GridLayout>
```

ArmyBuilder.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_army_builder);

    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    //creates the Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

BarracksUILarge.java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.barracks_ui_large, container, false);
    mDarkGrid = (GridLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.dark_grid);
    mElixGrid = (GridLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.elix_grid);

    BuildableObjData buildableObjData = new BuildableObjData();
    mElixTroopArray = buildableObjData.getBuildableArray(getActivity(), Utilities.ELIXER_TYPE_ELIXER, Utilities.BUILDABLE_TYPE_TROOP);

    buildBarracksGridUI(mElixTroopArray, Utilities.ELIXER_TYPE_ELIXER, mElixGrid);




    return mView;
}
```

styles-sw720dp-port

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="barracks_large_orientation">
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

styles-sw720dp-land

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="barracks_large_orientation">
      <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be on your fragment layout. Do you have different files for it as well?

Comment: do you have `barracks_ui_large` layout. please post its code. also `BarracksUILarge` is an activity or fragment.

Comment: @aloupas there is only one layout for barracks_ui_large.  I have tried moving that to different layout folders as well to see if that did anything.

Comment: @Tauqir, I did post the barracks_ui_large.xml and BarracksUILarge is a fragments.  Thanks.

Comment: No that would not make any difference. If you omit all other code in fragment and just inflate the view does it work? Comment buildBarracksGRidUI method. And check if mView is not null

Comment: Please check your question. There is no code for `barracks_ui_large` in your question. Also try above comment.

Comment: I commented out everything and it still crashed.  I changed the orientation from the @style reference to vertical and it worked.  So that appears to be my issue.  Thanks, I have posted my styles that I was referring to, any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Tauqir, sorry you are correct I mislabeled it.  I have corrected it

Comment: can you please update whether you have imported `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` inside `BarracksUILarge`